# Is there any website to cross verify?

Tags: patentability, verification

I have a concept and I would like to patent it. So is there any website available to cross verify that my concept is not in violation with already patented concept?

Any other sources will also be appreciable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skillful patent search requires carefully designed keywords. you can find relevant information using databases like:-

1. [Google Patents](http://www.google.co.in/advanced_patent_search)
2. [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.co.in/)
3. [European Patent Office](http://worldwide.espacenet.com/advancedSearch?locale=en_EP)
4. [US Patents](http://patft.uspto.gov/netahtml/PTO/index.html)
5. [WIPO](http://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/search.jsf)

Keep in mind that you need to see search help of respective databases.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to very thoroughly and clearly describe your concept and match it part by part to existing patents if you really want to patent it. This is a very detailed process and should be done very carefully before you file your patent.